# Make a single TreeViewNode non-selectable

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, winui

I'm trying to make the root `TreeViewNode` of my WinUI `TreeView` to act as a non-selectable "folder" for its selectable child nodes. However, the [`SelectionMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.treeview.selectionmode) property is available only for the whole `TreeView` and not separate instances of `TreeViewNode`.

How can I disable selection of a single node, while still keeping it enabled for the expand/collapse functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I disable selection of a single node, while still keeping it enabled for the expand/collapse functionality?

If we just simply set the node's `IsEnabled` property as false, it could suit for your scenario, but it will also disable expand/collapse functionality. So we need implement expand/collapse functionality independently. We could bind `TreeViewItem` `IsExpanded` property with bool value, and use it to expand/collapse the node.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FolderTemplate" x:DataType="local:ExplorerItem">
    <TreeViewItem
        AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind Name}"
        IsEnabled="False"
        IsExpanded="{Binding ElementName=MyTreeView, Path=DataContext.IsOpen, Mode=OneWay}"
        IsSelected="{x:Bind IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Width="20" Source="../Assets/folder.png" />
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TreeViewItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

**code behind**.

```
private bool _isOpen;
public bool IsOpen
{
    get
    {
        return _isOpen;
    }

    set
    {
        _isOpen = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsOpen");
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
 IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: Thanks! But `IsEnabled="False"` disables all user input, right? Is there a way to catch a click on the chevron, so I can update `IsOpen`'s value?

Comment: No, if you have disable the root node, it will disable user input, the chevron can't accept  click any more. we suggest you place the specific button to process IsOpen property.